# Refreshing the values on close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a flight tracker here and I want to have it so it when you are viewing a flight you can click close and then search a new flight and display the details for that... Currently if you search LAX-JKF it will show you all the current flights in air but if you click close and search LAX-SFO it will still list the LAX-JFK flights, however in the console it is actually displaying the correct search information it just does not append it to the screen.

The modal that we are working with is myModal2... And there is actually a hid function on it, maybe thats why its not working.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Flight info for <div id="results"></div></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <div id="results"></div>
        <div id="map_div" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>

        <table class="table" id="clouds">

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Cloud Type</th>
              <th>Cloud Altitude</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table class="table" id="info">

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Tail Number</th>
              <th>Meal Service</th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="modal2">


  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">All current Flights</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="showThis">
          <div id="results"></div>
          <div id="map_div" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">



          <table class="table" id="search">

            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Ident</th>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>



        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="refresh()" >Close</button>
          <script>

            function refresh() {
              // $("#origin_text").html=""
              // console.log("Test");
              document.getElementById("origin_text").value = "" //clearing the origin text box and dest text
              document.getElementById("destination_text").value = ""

            }
          </script>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<span id="airport">
```

Welcome to Skytime
Real Live Flight Tracking
By Ryan Holstein

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">



  <div id="bottom">
    <img alt="787" src="./Skytime_files/787nightedit-6cb8bcca496484b3e4746781c18bbccf.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;">
  </div>

  <div id="submitfield" style="margin-top:-500px">

    <p id="identflight1" style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:100px;color:white;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);margin-right:550px">&nbsp&nbsp<u>Instructions</u>
      <br/>&nbsp&nbsp1. Enter the airport code of where you are flying from and to. i.e From: KLAX TO: KJFK
      <br/>&nbsp&nbsp2. Click search and Select which flight you want to track.
      <br/>&nbsp&nbsp3. Then enjoy real live flight tracking!
      <br/>

      <div id="megatron" style="color:black;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);height:200px;">
    </p>
    <h1 id="h1">Enter a flight ident to track</h1>
    <input type="text" name="ident" id="ident_text" placeholder="airport code">

    <button type="submit" id="go_button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Go</button>
    <p></p>

    <p id="originid1"><span id="from">From</span>
      <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin_text">
    </p>

    <p id="destinationid1"><span id="to">To</span>
      <input type="text" name="origin" id="destination_text">
      <!--   <button id= "go_button">Go</button>
    <button id= "go_button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Go</button> -->

      <button type="submit" id="search_button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">search</button>
      </div>
    </p>

  </div>


</form>





<script type="text/javascript" src="./Skytime_files/jsapi"></script>





<script type="text/javascript">
  var fxml_url = (MY API KEY)


  var flightOrigin;
  var flightDestination;
  var airport;
  var identAir;
  var aircraft;
  var originCity;
  var destinationCity;


  google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["map"]
  });


   // When the button is clicked, fetch the details about the entered flight ident.
  $(function () {
    $('#go_button').click(function () {
      wellLookitUp(fxml_url, $('#ident_text').val());
    });



    $('#search_button').click(function () {
      console.log($('#origin_text').val());
      console.log($('#destination_text').val());
      console.log($('#search').val());
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: fxml_url + 'Search',
        data: {
          'query': "-origin " + $('#origin_text').val() + " -destination " + $('#destination_text').val(),
          'howMany': 10,
          'offset': 0
        },
        success: function (result) {

          console.log(result.SearchResult.aircraft[0]);
          for (i = 0; i < result.SearchResult.aircraft.length; i++) {
            s = result.SearchResult.aircraft[i]
            // console.log(s.ident, s.destination)
            // $('#search').append($("<tr><td>" + s.ident + "</td><td>" + s.destination + "</td></tr>"));
            $('#search').append($('<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="wellLookitUp2(\'' + fxml_url + '\',\'' + s.ident + '\');return false;">' + s.ident + '</a></td></tr>'));
            console.log(results);
            $("#showThis").hide();

          }

        },

        error: function (data, text) {
          alert('Failed to fetch flight: ' + data);
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        }

      });

    });

  });

  function wellLookitUp(fxml_url, ident) {
    // $('#modal2').modal('hide');
    // $('#modal2').modal('hide');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: fxml_url + 'InFlightInfo',

      data: {
        'ident': ident
      },
      success: function (result) {

        // display some textual details about the flight.
        var flight = result.InFlightInfoResult;
        flightOrigin = flight.origin;
        flightDestination = flight.destination;
        airport = flight.Taf;
        identAir = flight.faFlightID;

        $('#results').html('Flight ' + flight.ident + ' from ' + flightOrigin + ' to ' + flightDestination + ' Altitude: ' + flight.altitude + ' Groundspeed ' + flight.groundspeed); //+ ' Depature Time' + flight.departureTime + ' Arrival Time' + flight.arrivalTime );

        // display the route on a map.
        fetchAndRenderRoute(flight.faFlightID);
      },

      error: function (data, text) {
        alert('Failed to fetch flight: ' + data);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    });
  }


   // Fetch the planned route for a specified flight_id.
  function fetchAndRenderRoute(flight_id) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: fxml_url + 'DecodeFlightRoute',
      data: {
        'faFlightID': flight_id
      },
      success: function (result) {
        // Initialize a data table using the Google API.
        var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        table.addColumn('number', 'Lat');
        table.addColumn('number', 'Lon');
        table.addColumn('string', 'Name');

        // Insert all of the points into the data table.
        console.log(result);
        var points = result.DecodeFlightRouteResult.data;
        table.addRows(points.length);
        for (rowid = 0; rowid < points.length; rowid++) {
          table.setCell(rowid, 0, points[rowid].latitude);
          table.setCell(rowid, 1, points[rowid].longitude);
          table.setCell(rowid, 2, points[rowid].name + ' (' + points[rowid].type + ')');
        }

        // Render the data table into a map using Google Maps API.
        var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
        map.draw(table, {
          showTip: true,
          showLine: true,
          lineWidth: 3,
          lineColor: '#009900'
        });

        addMetar();
        addTaf();
        addSearch();
        // addFlightInfo();



      },
      error: function (data, text) {
        alert('Failed to decode route: ' + data);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    });
  }



  function wellLookitUp2(fxml_url, ident) {
    // $('#modal2').modal('hide');
    // $('#modal2').modal('hide');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: fxml_url + 'InFlightInfo',

      data: {
        'ident': ident
      },
      success: function (result) {

        // display some textual details about the flight.
        var flight = result.InFlightInfoResult;
        flightOrigin = flight.origin;
        flightDestination = flight.destination;
        airport = flight.Taf;
        identAir = flight.faFlightID;
        $("#showThis").show();
        $('.modal-body').html('Flight ' + flight.ident + ' from ' + flightOrigin + ' to ' + flightDestination + ' Altitude: ' + flight.altitude + ' Groundspeed ' + flight.groundspeed); //+ ' Depature Time' + flight.departureTime + ' Arrival Time' + flight.arrivalTime );



        // display the route on a map.
        fetchAndRenderRoute(flight.faFlightID);
      },

      error: function (data, text) {
        alert('Failed to fetch flight: ' + data);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    });
  }


  function addMetar() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: fxml_url + 'MetarEx',
      data: {
        'airport': flightOrigin,
        'howMany': 1,
        'offset': 0,
        'startTime': (new Date()).getTime()
      },
      success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.MetarExResult.metar);
        for (rowid = 0; rowid < result.MetarExResult.metar.length; rowid++) {
          m = result.MetarExResult.metar[rowid]
          console.log(m.cloud_type, m.cloud_altitude)
          $('#clouds').append($("<tr><td>" + m.cloud_type + "</td><td>" + m.cloud_altitude + "</td></tr>"));
        }

      },

      error: function (data, text) {
        alert('Failed to fetch flight: ' + data);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    });
  }


  function addTaf() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: fxml_url + 'AirlineFlightInfo',
      data: {
        'faFlightID': identAir
      },
      success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.AirlineFlightInfoResult);
        b = result.AirlineFlightInfoResult
        //          console.log(b.meal_service)
        $('#info').append($("<tr><td>" + b.tailnumber + "</td><td>" + b.meal_service + "</td></tr>"));

      },

      error: function (data, text) {
        alert('Failed to fetch flight: ' + data);
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }

    });
  }
</script>
<script src="./Skytime_files/saved_resource" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="./Skytime_files/ui+en.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./Skytime_files/format+en,default+en,ui+en,map+en.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: is there any code left?!

Comment: what do you mean, is there any code left?

Comment: I have more code but this is the code that would be controlling thet